# Is it possible to connect to a computer connected to a WiFi router

Tags: wireless, ethernet

I am connected to a Motorola WiFi router and there is another computer (a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu) connected to the same WiFi router via a LAN cable. Is it possible to access the Raspberry Pi from my computer (with Ubuntu)? I could directly connect to the Raspberry Pi and access when connected using the LAN cable directly. However, I cannot access the Pi when things are connected via WiFi router.

When directly connected with computer, I used

`ssh <username>@<IP>`

However the same is not working (not responsive) when connecting via the WiFi.

Comment: How are you trying to connect? For example, with ssh? It's certainly possible to do so. The computer will probably have a different IP address when it's connected over wifi than ethernet.

Comment: You can access the GUI with VNC https://raspberrytips.com/use-vnc-raspberry-pi/

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, I connected via ssh only. How to find this "different" IP address?

Comment: @SKPS There's no clear way to identify it from the Ubuntu machine, the wifi router's admin panel may identify what systems have what IP addresses, but that's beyond the scope of Ask Ubuntu to help you get to that.  It'd be easier to access the other device directly, get the IP address it has assigned to it, and then connect via SSH.

Comment: you can try to connect using the hostname: ssh <username>@<hostmame>.local

Comment: @Jean-Marie Thanks. That helped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nmap.

```
nmap -p 22 --open 192.168.1.1-254
```

For instance will scan the 192.168.1.X subnet for machines with an open port 22.

To get nmap, use:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap
```

So if you know what subnet you're on, you can do this pretty easily. If you don't know, use ifconfig. Use:

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
```

if it's not installed. Then ifconfig will show your configuration.

```
enp0s31f6: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.30.218.212  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.30.218.255
        ...
```

In my case, my computer is on the 10.30.218.X subnet.